# In Hibernate HQL, how do i filter the results of a joined Table parented to my main Table?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a parent Table, called "PN", which in it's entity contains a list of another Entity "PnDett", which is related to the first table. 
I want to execute a query that will give me the list of PN with my where condition, but that will filter the list of "PnDett" also based on a where condition. 
How can i achieve this?

This is the PN mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PN")
public class Pn implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2556879508428749494L;

@Id
@Column(name="ID_PN", unique = true, nullable = false)
private BigDecimal idPN;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="DATA_DOC")
private Date dataDoc;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="DATA_COMP_BANC")
private Date dataCompBanc;

@Column(name="STATO_PN")
private String statoPN;

@Column(name="TESTO_TESTATA")
private String testoTestata;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="DATA_INVIO_SAP")
private Date dataInvioSap;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="DATA_INS")
private Date dataIns;

@Column(name="ID_UTENTE_AGG")
private BigDecimal idUtenteAgg;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="DATA_CONTABILE")
private Date dataContabile;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="DATA_REND_INTEGR")
private Date dataRendIntegr;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="DATA_AGG")
private Date dataAgg;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pn")
private Set<PnDett> pnDetts = new HashSet<>(0);
```

This is the PnDett mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PN_DETT")
public class PnDett implements java.io.Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2556879508428749494L;

@Id
@Column(name="ID_PN_DETT", unique = true, nullable = false)
private BigDecimal idPNDett;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ID_PN", nullable=false)
private Pn pn;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID_DOM_TIPO_SCRITTURA")
private DomTipoScrittura domTipoScrittura;

@Column(name="TIPO_DOCUMENTO")
private String tipoDocumento;

@Column(name="ID_CALCOLO")
private String idCalcolo;


@Column(name="CONTO_COGE")
private String contoCoge;

@Column(name = "IMPORTO_AVERE")
private BigDecimal importoAvere;

@Column(name = "IMPORTO_DARE")
private BigDecimal importoDare;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID_UTENTE")
private Utente utente;

@Column(name = "DATA_INS")
private Date dataIns;

@Column(name = "TIPO_DETTAGLIO")
private String tipoDettaglio;

@Column(name = "SE_CANC")
private Integer seCancellato;
```

In HQL, i wrote this query "select * from Pn firstNote where firstNote.dataContabile = (a param i put myself, in this case 20 april 2020) and firstNote.pnDetts.seCancellato = (a param i put myself, in this case 0) and firstNote.pnDetts.importoDare <> 0 or firstNote.pnDetts.importoAvere <> 0"

The results are, quite frankly, a mess. I have only two lines in my PN table that have the parameter dataContabile set at 20 april 2020, and yet i get 18 results, and the results are an Object[] which somehow containes both entities. Inside the PN object i do have the pnDetts list filtered to match the date i'm searching them for, but the other filters don't even work. How can i fix this mess? Ideally, my result should be a list of two PN objects that have the pnDetts list filtered, but i don't know how to achieve this.

Edit: 
Ok, i've made an SQL query and found out that the PnDett lines related to that date that have either importoDare <> 0 or importoAvere<>0 are exactly 18, that's why i get 18 sets of objects[]. But how can i have just two PN objects, with the list inside filtered instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the filter work, we can make use of `fetch`, this will make sure that the initial query fetches all the required data.

```java
select * from Pn firstNote join fetch firstNote.pnDetts pnd where firstNote.dataContabile = :param1 and pnd.seCancellato = :param2 and pnd.importoDare <> 0 or pnd.importoAvere <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned by Vishnu you can use `join fetch`, but there are many issues with such an approach. Since the result of the query are managed entities, filtering the collection is problematic. When your transaction finishes, the filtered out elements might be removed so it's important that you immediately detach all entities after such a query e.g. view `entityManager.clear()`.

If you also want `Pn` objects that have empty `pnDetts` because nothing matches, you are out of luck with `join fetch` and have to use a normal join like this:

```
SELECT firstNote, pnd
FROM Pn firstNote 
LEFT JOIN firstNote.pnDetts pnd 
   ON pnd.seCancellato = :param2 AND pnd.importoDare <> 0 
   OR pnd.importoAvere <> 0
WHERE firstNote.dataContabile = :param1
```

This is a scalar query which will return a `Object[]` so you have to collect the lists manually.